# Popular uma list view em tempo de execução com DynamicAppearance

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Bom dia,  estou tentando adicionar itens a uma listview em tempo de execução. Nesse item a um texto e uma imagem, a parte do texto funcionou normal, porém a imagem não, ela é adicionada normalmente, porém é feito para todos os outros itens, ela tinha que ser igual o texto, cada item com o seu.  Segue o codigo:

```
 anitem : TListViewItem;
        txt : TListItemText;
        img : TListItemImage;
begin

    with FrmMain do
    begin

      anitem :=Listview1.items.add;

       with anitem do
       begin

        txt := TListItemText(Objects.FindDrawable('Text1'));
        txt.Text := S.Nome;
        //the image  part
        img := TListItemImage(Objects.FindDrawable('Image2'));

        img.Bitmap := s.Icone;
       end;

    end; 



//A rotina que estava com problema: 

    procedure TfrmMain.crialista;
    var
    Aux1 : TStringDynArray; // Usado para trocar o nome.exe por nome_Icon
    icone : string;          // Recebe o caminho completo para pegar o icone
    Programa : Tprograma;  //  Contem todas as informações do programa , é passado para cada item da listbox.
    Path : string;   //acho que não serve de nada
        // tb não usa pra nada
      Aux : integer;
     ARPrograma : array of TPrograma ;
      searchaux: string;
      Contador : integer;
    begin
         listview1.Items.clear;

              TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
         begin
          QryEIS.Close;
          QryEIS.open; 
            Contador:= 0 ;

           SetLength(ARPrograma, QRyEIS.RecordCount );
          QryEIS.First;        
          while not QryEIS.Eof do
            begin
              QryDiretorio.Close;

              QryDiretorio.ParamByName('NomeDoSistema').Value:= QryEIS.FieldByName('DescricaoEIS').Value;
                 QryDiretorio.Open;
              // Pegando o Icone do programa...

              if QryDiretorio.RecordCount = 0  then //escrever o erro aqui
                else
                begin

              aux1 :=     splitString( QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value, '.')  ;
              icone := 'F:\Sistemas\Icones\Launcher\' +aux1[0]+'_Icon.ico';
             // ImageList1.AddMasked(Bmp,clFuchsia);
              imagecontrol1.LoadFromFile(icone);
              ARPrograma[Contador].Icone := imagecontrol1.bitmap;


              ARPrograma[Contador].Nome:= QryDiretorio.FieldByName('NomeDoSistema').Value;
              ARPrograma[Contador].NomeExe :=  QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value;
                 ARPrograma[Contador].SingleUser := QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value ;
              // Caminho da unidade C (PathC) e da unidade F (Path)
              if QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value = 'T' then
              begin
            ARPrograma[Contador].path := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Origem').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
                ARPrograma[Contador].pathC := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+qryNome.FieldByname('NomeUsuario').Value+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
                ARPrograma[Contador].DiretorioUser := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+qryNome.FieldByname('NomeUsuario').Value;
                 ARPrograma[Contador].Diretorio   :=trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value);
                 ARPrograma[Contador].SingleUser := QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value ;

              end
              else
              begin
              ARPrograma[Contador].path := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Origem').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
              ARPrograma[Contador].pathC := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
              ARPrograma[Contador].Diretorio := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value);
              end ;



                aux := fileage(ARPrograma[Contador].path);
               ARPrograma[Contador].DataMod := FileDateToDateTime(aux);
             ARPrograma[Contador].Versao  :=  Sto_GetFmtFileVersion(Programa.path , '');
              if Programa.Versao <> '' then 
                  begin
                  aux1 := splitString (Programa.Versao , '.');
                 ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[1] := strtoint(aux1[0]);
                 ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[2] := strtoint(aux1[1]);
                  ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[3] := strtoint(aux1[2]);
                  ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[4] := strtoint(aux1[3]);
                  end;


                  if fileExists(programa.pathC) then
                begin


                  ARPrograma[Contador].VersaoC := Sto_GetFmtFileVersion(Programa.pathC , '');
                   if Programa.VersaoC <> '' then   //  Mesma coisa do comentario do F:
                  begin
                  aux1 := splitString (Programa.VersaoC , '.');
                 ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[1] := strtoint(aux1[0]);
                  ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[2] := strtoint(aux1[1]);
                  ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[3] := strtoint(aux1[2]);
                  ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[4] := strtoint(aux1[3]);
                  end;
                end ;


            // Here i call the CriaFrama. 
              criaframa(ARPrograma[Contador], Contador);

               contador := Contador +1;
              end;


              QryEIS.Next;



              end;


             TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
             begin
    // some visual thing....

             end);

         end).Start;
    end;
```

Comment: Esse código dá erro ou não mostra a imagem?

Comment: Então , ele mostra uma imagem, na realidade a mesma imagem parar todos os itens, mas deveria mostrar varias imagens. O pessoa do forum em ingles respondeu. Vou só terminar aqui e vou posto a resposta aqui tb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então como foi dito nos comentario , um cara do forum em ingles respondeu. 
No final das conta o problema não estava nessa rotina e sim na rotina que chama essa.
Eu estava apontando todos os itens para o mesmo bitmap e não estava sincronizando as threads. Segue o Codigo funcionando

```
 procedure TfrmMain.crialista;
var
Aux1 : TStringDynArray; 
icone : string;          
Path : string;   
Aux : integer;
ARPrograma : array of TPrograma ;
searchaux: string;
Contador : integer;
bitmap : FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;
begin

     listview1.Visible := false;
 load_menu.Visible := true;
 Load_menu.Enabled :=  true;
     frmMain.LPrincipal.RemoveObject(0);
     listview1.Items.clear;
     searchaux:= searchBox1.Text;
     searchBox1.Text.Empty;
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
    var bitmap : FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;
     begin
      QryEIS.Close;
      QryEIS.open; 
       Contador:= 0 ;
       SetLength(ARPrograma, QRyEIS.RecordCount );
      QryEIS.First;        
      while not QryEIS.Eof do
        begin
          QryDiretorio.Close;

          QryDiretorio.ParamByName('NomeDoSistema').Value  := 
            QryEIS.FieldByName('DescricaoEIS').Value;
             QryDiretorio.Open;


          if QryDiretorio.RecordCount = 0  then 
            else
            begin

                   TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
        begin
           aux1 :=splitString( QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value, '.')  ;
           icone := 'F:\Sistemas\Icones\Launcher\' +aux1[0]+'_Icon.ico';
           BitMap := FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.CreateFromFile(icone); // aqui 
           ARPrograma[Contador].Icone := bitmap ;

        end);



          ARPrograma[Contador].Nome:= QryDiretorio.FieldByName('NomeDoSistema').Value;
          ARPrograma[Contador].NomeExe :=  QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value;
             ARPrograma[Contador].SingleUser := QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value ;

          if QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value = 'T' then
          begin
        ARPrograma[Contador].path := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Origem').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
            ARPrograma[Contador].pathC := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+qryNome.FieldByname('NomeUsuario').Value+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
            ARPrograma[Contador].DiretorioUser := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+qryNome.FieldByname('NomeUsuario').Value;
             ARPrograma[Contador].Diretorio   :=trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value);
             ARPrograma[Contador].SingleUser := QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value ;

          end
          else
          begin
          ARPrograma[Contador].path := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Origem').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
          ARPrograma[Contador].pathC := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
          ARPrograma[Contador].Diretorio := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value);
          end ;
          //Pega a versão do .exe da unidade F:


            aux := fileage(ARPrograma[Contador].path);
           ARPrograma[Contador].DataMod := FileDateToDateTime(aux);
         ARPrograma[Contador].Versao  :=  Sto_GetFmtFileVersion(Programa.path , '');
          if Programa.Versao <> '' then //caso não seja nulo , coloca no array de integer , para ficar mais facil de comparar na hora de atualizar. (fica em Udetalhes)
              begin
              aux1 := splitString (Programa.Versao , '.');
             ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[1] := strtoint(aux1[0]);
             ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[2] := strtoint(aux1[1]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[3] := strtoint(aux1[2]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[4] := strtoint(aux1[3]);
              end;

              if fileExists(programa.pathC) then
            begin


              ARPrograma[Contador].VersaoC := Sto_GetFmtFileVersion(Programa.pathC , '');
               if Programa.VersaoC <> '' then  
              begin
              aux1 := splitString (Programa.VersaoC , '.');
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[1] := strtoint(aux1[0]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[2] := strtoint(aux1[1]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[3] := strtoint(aux1[2]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[4] := strtoint(aux1[3]);
              end;
            end ;


          TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
        begin
             criaframa(ARPrograma[Contador], Contador);

        end);


           contador := Contador +1;
          end;

          QryEIS.Next;



          end;


        TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
        begin

          listview1.Visible := true;
          load_menu.Visible := false;
          Load_menu.Enabled :=  false;
           searchBox1.Text :='';
        end);

     end).Start;
end;
```